# PHP: Store array output in a variable for later use

Tags: php

Script taken from http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/get-geo-ip-information/

```
    .
    .                   
    .
             //Array where results will be stored
                       $ipInfo=array();

                       //check response from ipserver for above patterns
                       foreach ($patterns as $key => $pattern)
                       {
                               //store the result in array
                               $ipInfo[$key] = preg_match($pattern,$response,$value) && !empty($value[1]) ? $value[1] : 'not found';
                       }


                      return $ipInfo;
         }
```

This displays the **$ipInfo**.

The thing is that i don't want it to display **$ipInfo**. I want to save the output in a variable and then **echo** it later, when i need it in another place. How can i do that?

Comment: There is no outputting in this script. Wherever this function is called there must be an `echo` or `print_r`.

Comment: Your above code already *returns* a variable. You just need to pass its result around.

Comment: @Kolink Yes, your suggestion is right. Now i feel so dumb that i didn't see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print_r(geoCheckIP($ip));
```

This is what's doing the outputting. Just assign to a variable instead:

```
$somevar = geoCheckIP($ip);
```

This is trivial PHP that you really should know.

Comment: You could also set it to a `global` variable within this function and than reinitialize as global variable in any other function that gets called, and get it that way instead of returning the variable.